# How to select all data from one table and records from another table matching data in first selection. All in one query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables `Messages` and `Files`. The `Files` table references `Messages` through its `message_id` foreign key which corresponds to the `Messages`'s primary key named `message_id` as well. A message entity may or may not have a file but there cannot be a file without a message.

So I want to select everything in one query. All the messages and if there is a file for a message then select a file as well. As far as I understand the resulting query should look something like this:

```
select * from Messages union select * from Files where message_id = Messages.message_id
```

unfortunately this simple query is not valid. I also tried using joins:

```
select * from Messages 
left outer join Files on Messages.message_id = Files.message_id 
union 
select * from Files 
left outer join Messages on Messages.message_id = Files.message_id
```

but it gives me only those messages which have a file. Using subqueries doesn't seem to be a solution. So how do I do this?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want data from one table and, if it exists, data from another table then why does a simple left outer join not work?

```
select * from Messages 
left outer join Files on 
Messages.message_id = Files.message_id
```

Comment: Somehow it doesn't select message_id from Messages except those ones which have a file

Comment: Probably because you are using SELECT * and this causes issues where columns with the same name exist in both tables. Try explicitly listing all the columns, including table aliases

Comment: @AndreyChernukha this is not possible. Even if all columns exist in both tables still the left join would not behave like an inner join: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f60f0609a915b9e495e4aa4ee2a00eb2 So, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You want a full outer join here, which SQLite does not directly support.  You may emulate it with a union, along the lines of what you have already tried:

```sql
SELECT m.*, f.*
FROM Messages m
LEFT JOIN Files f ON m.message_id = f.message_id
UNION ALL
SELECT m.*, f.*
FROM Files f
LEFT JOIN Messages m ON m.message_id = f.message_id
WHERE m.message_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Somehow it doesn't select message_id from Messages except those ones which have a file

Answer (score 1):

The key point of your requirement is:

> A message entity may or may not have a file but **there cannot be a
> file without a message**

which is the definition of a `LEFT` join of `Messages` to `Files`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Messages m LEFT JOIN Files f
ON f.message_id = m.message_id;
```

Comment: Somehow it doesn't select message_id from Messages except those ones which have a file

Comment: @AndreyChernukha This is not possible for a LEFT join. Can you reproduce your issue with sample data in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27?